# por qué no inicializa la variable authorize con pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Básicamente estoy tratando de verificar a los user con un rol asignado (administrador y profesor) para que profesor no pueda acceder a la ruta cursos, es justo ahí que sale un error que la variable no está inicializada.

este es mi controlador

```
class CursosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_usuario!
  before_action :set_curso, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    authorize Curso
    @cursos = Curso.all


  end

  def show

  end

  def new

    @curso = Curso.new


  end

  def create
    @curso = Curso.new(curso_params)
    if @curso.save
      redirect_to cursos_path
      flash.notice= 'curso creado'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    if @curso.update(curso_params)
      redirect_to cursos_path
      flash.notice= 'curso actualizado'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @curso.destroy
    redirect_to cursos_path
    flash.alert= 'Curso eliminado'
  end

  private

  def set_curso
    @curso =Curso.find(params[:id])
  end

  def curso_params
    params.require(:curso).permit(:codigo,:nombre)
  end
end
```

este es mi curso_policy.rb

```
class CursoPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :curso

  def initialize(user, curso)
    @user = user
    @curso = curso
  end

  def index?
    @user.has_role? :administrador
  end
end
```

No sé cual será el error, del por qué no inicializa la varibale authorize.

Comment: ¿Podrías pegar el error que ves, con traza de la excepción y todo? Sin más información, es difícil ver cual es el problema. También, ¿podrías explicar como funciona tu autenticación? ¿Qué hace `authenticate_usuario!`? ¿Tienes un méthodo `current_user`? Es posible que tengas `current_usuario`, pero Pundit espera que tengas `current_user`.

Comment: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<CursosController:0x0000563674cfb920> Did you mean? current_usuario
Extracted source (around line #6):
4
5
6
7
8
9
              

  def index
    authorize Curso
    @cursos = Curso.all


Ese es el error que sale, cuando ejecuto el server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según [la documentación](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#customize-pundit-user), deberías definir cual es el usuario que usará pundit, así que agrega en tu `ApplicationController`:

```
def pundit_user
  current_usuario
end
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias